# ng model GetText() method issue Selenium WebDriver with Java

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Action:
getting the value from the text box using GetText() method with using Selenium webdriver

HTMl code

```
<input class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid dirty ng-touched" type="text" placeholder="Search Query" my-enter="SaveBind('Search');" ng-model="Query.SearchTerm" name="headerSearch">
```

above one is an Input type with text control, so i want extract the value from the text box

my Xpath:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//input[@ng-model='Query.SearchTerm']")
public WebElement searchQuery;
```

if i used getText method i am getting empty value

```
String query = searchQuery.getText();
```

but when we pass the value thru send key its working perfectly and enterd value paste in the control

```
searchQuery.sendKeys("Welcome");
```

my doubt:
entered values are not shown in the HTML tag? then how can i extract the value from the text box?
is it possible to do an automate the Angular Js?

Screen shot attached[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, entered values are not shown in the html. To get the entered value you need to use `getAttribute()` method

```
String query = searchQuery.getAttribute("value");
```

Comment: I have tried both of the way using webelement methods .getAttribute("value") and using javascriptexecutor also but it is returning null. (Text is visible on page but not in html as value or any attribute)
My application is angular js. Any one have any idea how to get that text.

Comment: @AmitRajput Please post new question with the relevant code and html.